# Add term from a file to another perl

Tags: perl

file 1

```
word1 word2 word3 
 word1 word4 word2
 word2 word4 word2
```

file 2

```
word1 word8 word5....
```

the result I want is to add all next words of a word from file 1 if it exist in file 2 . Every word added should be added once time .

so the resulat

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word8 word5....
```

i try this but it dont give me the solution

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE1,"./fichier1.txt" or die "Cannot open fichier1.txt";
open FILE2,"./fichier2.txt" or die "Cannot open fichier2.txt";
open FILE3,">./resultat.txt" or die "Cannot create resultat.txt";

while (<FILE1>)
{
  chomp;
  /[^\ ]*$/;
  $common = $&;
  $begin = $`;
  chop $begin;
  $array{$common} = $begin;
}
close FILE1;
while (<FILE2>)
{
  chomp;
  /^[^\ ]*\ /;
  $common = $&;
  chop $common;
  $end = $';
  print FILE3 "$array{$common} $common $end\n" if exists $array{$common};
}
close FILE2;
close FILE3;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain more clearly how to derive that result from those input files. Are the `<br/>` really in the input? What happens if `word4` is in file 2?

Comment: omit duplicate words and keep remaining things in the output file.

Comment: if word 4 is in file 2 we add the folowing term of word4 from file 1 to file 2  for exemple   if  file 2 is like this  word1 word8 word5 word4 ..  the resulat will be word1 word2 word3 word4 word8 word5 word2   so we add once de time word 2

Comment: @AlyaLetaief Will `fichier2.txt` contain only one line or more than one line?

Comment: more then one line surely   . resultat.txt will containt the same content of fichier2.txt but extended  with word add from fichier1.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
open $FILE1,'<','./fichier1.txt' or die "Cannot open fichier1.txt $!";
open $FILE2,'<','./fichier2.txt' or die "Cannot open fichier2.txt $!";
open $FILE3,'>', './resultat.txt' or die "Cannot create resultat.txt $!";
my %unique;
my @result;

sub pusher {
    for (split /\s+/, shift) {
        next unless $_;
        next if ($unique{$_});
        push @result, $_;
        $unique{$_} = 1;
    }
}

for(<$FILE1>, <$FILE2>) {
    pusher($_);
}
close($FILE1);
close($FILE2);
print $FILE3 join ' ', @result;
close($FILE3);
```

Comment: this script give this result word10 word1 word5 word3 word2 word4 word8 word9   but result should be  word1 word2 word3 word5 word9 word8 word5 word10

Comment: maybe so? word1 word2 word3 word5 word9 word4 word10

Comment: yes because word5 is in fichier2.txt already so we can delete it but when we see in fichier.txt word5 exist so then we shoud add the following word of word5 that is word9 but we don't add it because we added it  when we added following words of word1

Comment: file1   word1 word2 word3   word1 word5 word9  word2 word4 word8     file2  word1 word8 word5 word10                                                                                                                                    the result    word1 word2 word3 word5 word9 word8 word5 word10

Answer (score 0):

You want to write to file 3 all words from file 1, that are in file 2, and do it only once?

This will help you

```
open my $FILE1,"<","./fichier1.txt" or die "Cannot open fichier1.txt $!";
open my $FILE2,"<","./fichier2.txt" or die "Cannot open fichier2.txt $!";
open my $FILE3,">", "./resultat.txt" or die "Cannot create resultat.txt $!";
my %unique;

while(<$FILE2>) {
    my @words = split /\s/;
    $unique{$_} = 1 for @words;
}
close($FILE2);
while(<$FILE1>) {
        my @words = split /\s/; 
        for (@words) {
            if ($unique{$_}) {
                print $FILE3 "$_ ";
                delete $unique{$_};
            }   
        }    
}
```

this is my fichier1.txt

```
word1 word2 word3 
 word1 word5 word9
 word2 word4 word8
```

this is my fichier2.txt

```
word1 word8 word5 word10
```

this is my result.txt

```
word1 word5 word8
```

maybe I didn't understand task correctly

Comment: with this script result is empty

Comment: still produces empty result

Comment: i want to add in file 3 all flowing word  of the  word that exist  in file 2

Comment: no <br/> in the file. You cannot answer if you are unsure of the question

Comment: Post was edited and I haven't noticed changes. So it easy

Comment: the resultat.txt should be word1 word2 word3 word5 word9 word8 word5  word10

Comment: is order important?